# How can I change page setup units from inches to millimeters?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firewall, mozilla

Can anyone please suggest me that how can change default page setup "margins" from inches to millimeters in Firefox browser? I'm using 26.0 version.

Comment: My IS mm. Maybe is an auto-sett from regional settings ? Try to change your locale - FF or system wide - to an european country and check again.(I have both millimeters in FF26 and in FF29)

Answer (score 0):

it is because of the Firefox page size default,you can change FireFox page size from letter to A4 by ,typing about:config in address bar, then search print.printer_printer_name.print_paper_size_unit  from 0 to 1